# Is it possible to call Dart method from C++?

Tags: dart, dart-native-extension

How to call Dart method from C++ code? I want to try use Dart as scripting language in my application.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have two possibilities:

First, you can **embed the Dart VM into your C++ program**. See [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!topic/misc/qBuKmUBltas) (there is a GitHub example). This allows you to write you program in C++ and run Dart scripts. I don't think that this way is supported by the Dart team directly, you need to do many things yourself.

Second, you can **embed your C++ code into the Dart VM** as a native extension. See [this guide](http://www.dartlang.org/articles/native-extensions-for-standalone-dart-vm/) for details. This allows you to write your program in Dart and you can move performance critical parts or parts that need access to native libraries, to C++. There are many examples available.

Comment: Note that the tables have turned, the linked "this guide" page indicates that embedding the VM is now well-supported and the native-extension technique is retired.